# Trigger An Action Based on value change of DateTimeField in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I would like to fire an event immediately at/after a certain DateTimeField in a certain model equals the value of datetime.now(). It is a field that marks expiration of a product, so as soon as it expires I want to fire an event and execute some relevant code.

How to do that in Django?

P.S. Can I do that using Celery, since I plan to use it anyway for other parts of the project?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/#module-django.core.management) and then set up a [cron job](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job) that runs every minute. 
This cron polls for expired objects, and executes the relevant code.

```
import datetime
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

def compute_inactivity():
    expired_objects = MyModel.objects.filter(datetime__lte=datetime.datetime.now())
    for obj in expired_objects:
        #Take the necessary action

class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, **options):
       compute_expiry()
```

Comment: How will this scale? I have a number of load-balanced django app servers.

Comment: How many object do you think would expired every minute ? You can also look into tools like django-celery which can provide a more streamlined system

Comment: A small number of objects

Comment: Then run it on one of the server, since the backend database would be the same.